# how can I use 2 database models in Django programming?

Tags: html, django

in my models.py , I have 2 database named 'DB' and 'Rent'.

what I want to do in my html page is to subtract rented number ( which is in Rent database ) from total number ( which is in DB databases ).

I wonder if there is possible way to use for loop which first loop uses DB databases and second loop uses Rent databases.

point is that I have to lookup both databases every loop.

```html
{% for p in DB %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ p.product_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ r.rented_num }}</td> <!-- how can I do this??? -->
                            <td>{{ p.total_num }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/ this will probably help but... Try not to have multiple databases if you can.

Comment: Wait, you have 2 databases "in your models.py"? Don't you mean 2 models, or 2 tables?

Comment: ohh what I meant was 2 table not models.

Comment: Then it's all a matter of what data you're adding to the context in your views. You can add as much data as you want and any way you want before returning the response.